# Not working Dual monitor on Radeon HD 5450

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, external-monitor

I use Radeon HD 5450. I need work with Dual monitor.

**One try (Not Working):**

- The first monitor is in VGA onboard input.
- The second monitor on VGA Radeon 5450.

**Second try (Not Working):**

- The first monitor on VGA Radeon 5450.
- The second monitor on DVI Radeon 5450 (i use this adaptor DVI_VGA).

How i can play two monitor, this not working?

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What is not working? Did you use the monitor settings?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same card to work this way:

- Create new `xorg.conf` using `aticonfig --initial` (it is installed by packages fglrx/fglrx-updates), it complained about something but since I had no other option I ignored it
- move `xorg.conf` as root to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if necessary
- edit it so that the part `Virtual   3200 3200` appears in every `Subsection "Display"`
- Restart X (in my case `sudo service lightdm restart`)

My setup is like your second try but without an adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same video card recently. I had one DVI-HDMI and one VGA connected monitors. The problem was solved by replacing VGA cable to simple DVI cable. After replacing VGA monitors start working instantly without any additional configuration. So, final configuration is:

**Fisrt Display:** DVI-HDMI

**Second Display:** DVI-DVI

Open source driver from xorg-edgers ppa used. No lag, no tearing - everything is just fine.